# Can't understand inversion counting inside Merge sort algorithm (C#, Algorithms)

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a problem to understand the process of counting inversions using Merge sort algorithm (https://gist.github.com/dvorobiov/2038501).
In line 43,

```
inversions += leftList.Count - i;
```

why don't just do

```
inversions++
```

Comment: Because `i` isn't always going to get 1 bigger each time that code is run?

Comment: Because `leftList.Count - i` won't always be `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is executed when `(leftList[i] > rightList[j])`.

This fact means that `rightList[j]` is smaller than all the right piece of the `leftlist` - so such case reveals `leftList.Count - i` new inversions